# Access Form show other table's fields of selected combobox item

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to Microsoft Access. This is the structure I have:

Table `Suppliers` with fields `Name`, `Address`, `Zip`, `PhoneNumber` 
Table `Purchases` with fields `Supplier`, `Address`, `Zip`, `PhoneNumber`  (and some other irrelevant ones)

The `Supplier` field in the `Purchases` table should contain a reference to a record in the `Suppliers` table.

Now I am making a form so the user can enter `Purchases` records. It has a combobox to choose the `Supplier` and some text fields for `Address`, `Zip`, `PhoneNumber`. What I want is that when the user selects a `Supplier`, the values for the `Address`, `Zip`, `PhoneNumber` will be copied from the selected `Supplier` to the corresponding text fields in the form.

How can I achieve this result using Visual Basic code?

Comment: I assume this form is for ADDING records only (no mods to existing data?)

Comment: Yes, it is for adding records only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First a word of caution. Copying date is sometimes the wrong approach, as it breaks relational integrity of your data. That said, sometimes there can be perfectly valid reasons for doing so. I won't go further into that here.

One of the simplest ways is to ensure you have the data available in the recordsource of your Supplier combobox. They do NOT need to be visible, you can set the column width to 0 to hide them. 
Lets pretend your recordsource is:

```
SELECT Suppliers.[Name], Suppliers.Address, Suppliers.Zip, Suppliers.PhoneNumber from Suppliers
```

Now in the combobox AfterUpdate event we copy the data.

```
Private Sub SupplierCombo_AfterUpdate()
  If IsNull(Me.SupplierCombo) Then
    Me.txtAddress=Null
    Me.txtZip=Null
    Me.txtPhoneNumber=Null
  Else
    Me.txtAddress=me.SupplierCombo.Column(1)
    Me.txtZip=me.SupplierCombo.Column(2)
    Me.txtPhoneNumber=me.SupplierCombo.Column(3)
  End If

End Sub
```

If your textboxes are bound, you are done. If they are unbound, you will also need code in the forms Current event to ensure the textboxes update as you move from 1 record to the next.

Hope that Helps

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. But why is there a null check?

Comment: The Null check is for when a user clears the combobox. You would not want to leave the "old" data in the textboxes.